# Samba4 share: Windows can read/write, OS X can only read

Tags: mac-osx, samba4

In the last few days I've played around with Samba4. I've created a new domain, some shares and everything works well. At least when I'm working with windows. We have some OSX clients an I'm testing the shares with lion. Now the problem is: With windows I can read and write files and folders, but when I connect via OSX, I can read and delete everything, create and edit folders, but I'm not allowed to create or edit files. At this time I'm testing with the Administrator user which should have all permissions.

What I've done so far:

- Creating the share in smb.conf with "writable=yes"
- Set the filesystem permissions to 777 (filesystem supports acls)
- Setting the permissions via Windows for all "Domain Users" to full control

Do I need to set some special permissions for OSX? What bugs me is, that there seems to be a difference between files and folders...

Regards 
Gewürzwiesel

Comment: try remounting without acl to see if these are the problem. mount -oremount,noacl /dev/yourdisk /mnt/point
and restart samba after that.

Comment: Still no change. Windows can write, OSX can't...

Comment: check samba logs.

Comment: Meh... Logs didn't say anything about an error. So: I unistalled Samba4 and installed Samba3 :/